# How can I execute python script with command line flag

Tags: python-2.6

I have this bit of code:

```
of = open("oldfile")
nf = open("newfile",'w')
for line in of:
     if len(line) > 17:
             nf.write(line)

of.close()
nf.close()
```

and instead of specifying 17, I want to be able to use a variable put it in my scripts directory and execute it directly. If there is no flag, it could print something like 'scriptname'. If there is a flag, as there is below, it would execute the code.

> $ myscriptname -l 17 oldfile newfile

Comment: You question is a little bit confusing. You can use environment variables, command-line arguments passed to your script, read parameters from a file...

Comment: @khachik Can you tell me what you think I'm saying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [`optparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html?highlight=optparse#module-optparse) module for checking the flag and setting the value, or the newer (and better) [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) if you're willing to use 2.7+. As for *putting it in my scripts directory* I don't quite understand what you want exactly.

Comment: I have a directory in my path where I put shell scripts that can be called by name. I would also be using this as a script, as part of my command-line repetoire.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want quick and dirty access to the command line parameters:

```
import sys
print sys.argv # <-- this is an array containing all the command line parameters
```

If you want some more control, you can use the [optparse module](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html).